# Add a library path for .whl files to sys.path via a commandline option for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, python-import, sys.path

Is it possible to add a library path for .whl files to sys.path via a commandline option for python executable to execute a python script file?

`/path/to/python/executable/not/installed/in/system/python3 --modulespath "path/to/.whl/files/folder /path/to/my/script/file.py"`

Comment: or you could pip install that `.whl` file and run it normally?

Comment: Probably Not. I am calling python executable from nodejs shell module and am using embedded python to run. I got stuck with this. I wanted to avoid adding `import sys; sys.append(path)` to all executable files. So avoiding pip usage and environment variables completely here. Can I put and use an envrionment variable for pip without a python installation in linux system

Comment: try [PYTHONPATH or PYTHONSTARTUP](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)